# How to trigger bootstrap theme files to load on vanilla Domino 9.0.1 FP6 server WITHOUT OpenNTF extlib

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, xpages

I have an application using both the OpenNTF version of Bootstrap4Xpages and the OpenNTF version of the Extension Library, however now, with the advent of a new production server I wanted to NOT have to install either of these an just use the Vanilla extension library that comes with Domino 9.0.1 FP6.

My problem is, that after removing the dependency on bootrap4xpages, and leaving just the dependency on the extlib, I can figure out why, no matter what  theme i choose to extend in my theme resource, why I can't get the bootstrap resources from the extension library to load.

How do I do it? Theme name to extend? Do I actually need the Open NTF version of the ExtLib, or should I be able to do it with the IBM provided one?

[I tried extending 'Bootstrap3', 'Bootstrap3.2.0', 'bootstrapv3.2.0', and probably a various array of other things like this but to no avail...

The version of the extlib installed on the server is: [0EC8:0002-0F14] 07/04/2016 11:34:07 AM 189 ACTIVE com.ibm.xsp.extlib_9.0.1.v00_00_20160415-2200

I can't seem to directly match that up with any of the OpenNTF versions of the Extension Library either, to be able to install a same-for-same ext lib package into my designer 9.0 client.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far I know if you want Bootstrap 3 you need the Extension Library from OpenNTF or the plain vanilla files from Bootstrap which you need to add manually in a folder under WebContent.
Currently we are building an application without the OpenNTF ExtLib. It is not that hard to implement, but I can recommand the use of a Theme, where you can load all the required resources for Bootstrap, JQuery and other plugins.
To get all these files another useful tool is Bower, see my website. http://elstarit.nl/tag/bower/

Comment: We're using Bootstrap under WebContent via a theme on FP4. Relatively simple to implement.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge FP6 does not include updates to Extension Library. They have not been included in previous fix packs. It's possible that may change in the future, but there has been no announcement to date.